# How to show notifications even when app is killed like whatsapp or other famous apps?

Tags: android

I am creating an android app that targets API 34. I want to show notifications from server side to alert users of incoming requests but when i remove app from recent background, service is killed after 2 minutes. I am creating a notification using startForeground.
One more problem I've encountered is that notification is not hiding automatically even though I've set autoCancel to true.
Can anyone solve these issues perfectly by providing java codes? I would be highly obliged.

I have created a service that starts when mainactivity starts.. and restarts it if taskRemoved triggerd. I'm using START_STICKY in onStartCommand.

Comment: "whatsapp or other famous app" use Firebase Cloud Messaging for server-raised (push) notifications.

Comment: firebase is one of many check that list  -- OneSignal. OneSignal is a high volume push notification service for websites and mobile. ...
Google Cloud Messaging. Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a free service that enables developers to send. ...
Firebase. ...
Amazon SNS. ...
Kafka. ...
SignalR. ...
Pusher. ...
MQTT.